# how to get proper data in apigee baas when we inert data by end user in titanium alloy

Tags: javascript, json, titanium-alloy, apigee-baas

**index.xml**

```
      <Alloy>
        <Window class="container">
        <Label id="label">login here</Label>
        <TextField id="txtUser">username</TextField>
        <TextField id="pwd">password</TextField>
        <Button id="btnLogin" onClick="doLogin"></Button>
       </Window>
    </Alloy>

   index.js

        function doLogin(e) {
          var name = $.txtUser.value.toString();//txtUser is my textbox id
         var paswd = $.pwd.value.toString();  //pwd is my textbox id
      var jsonobject = {"username":'"'+name+'"',"password":'"'+ paswd+'"'};                    
         var url="api.usergrid.com/DHEERAJ123/DEMO1/logs?";
        var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
     onload:{ },
      onerror :{ }   
     });
          client.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'JSON');
            client.open("POST", url);
           client.send(JSON.stringify(jsonobject));
         }
   $.index.open();

    apigee baas output

         {
       "uuid": "6f07d50a-c48b-11e4-939c-ab932c123bc7",
       "type": "logs",
        "created": 1425706387024,
          "modified": 1425706387024,
        "metadata": {
          "path": "/logs/6f07d50a-c48b-11e4-939c-ab932c123bc7"
          },
       "password": "\"888\"",   // i had sent 888 but it come .....
       "username": "\"dheeraj\""// i had sent dheeraj but it save.....
          }
```

When I am inserting data in apigee using titanium alloy through end user, data in apigee is  not save in proper format, in apigee additional \ and "" are coming .....
how to overcome with this problem.....

Answer (score 0):

I think this:

```
var jsonobject = {"username":'"'+name+'"',"password":'"'+ paswd+'"'};
```

Should be:

```
var jsonobject = {"username":name,"password":paswd};
```